# Can Regex.Split get multiple whitespaces?

Tags: c#, regex, split

I have simple pattern:`\s+` to split whitespaces:

```
string temp="str1   str2   str3  ";
string pattern=@"\s+";
var tempArr=Regex.Split(temp,pattern);
```

So, result is `str1`,`str2`,`str3`.
But, I need to keep one whitespace per word (if exist):

```
'str1',' ','str2',' ','str3'.
```

Can I do that with `Regex.Split`, or should I use another way?

Comment: What about whitespace at the end?

Comment: @PranavCBalan,it should be missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than splitting at whitespaces, capture:

- consecutive non-whitespace characters - `(\S+)`
- consecutive whitespace characters, which are following by non-whitespace chracters - `(\s+(?=\S))` (using a [zero-width positive lookahead assertion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx))

Then convert matches that comprise of only whitespace to single spaces:

```cs
Regex regx = new Regex(@"(\S+)|(\s+(?=\S))");
var matches = regx.Matches(myString);

var values = matches.OfType<Match>().Select(m => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(m.Value) ? " " : m.Value).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex.Split will remove whatever is matched as the splitting pattern, and return the remaining things in an array, so it won't have array entries for the whitespace itself. You can just loop through and copy the array with added spaces as desired, or when you print it out.

However, if you really wanted the output as an array with the ' ' spaces as entries, you could first replace all whitespace with some arbitrary sequence such as "<#> <#>" then Regex.Split on "<#>". That would give you the array you specified. However you'd need to be careful that the arbitrary sequence wasn't ever a valid occurance in the real string, or you'd have to do pre and post-encoding/decoding, defeating the purpose of doing all this.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html
A third option is to use look-behind / look-ahead. Replace all white space with 3 spaces '  ', then, your Regex.Split matches all space characters preceded by a non-space, and all space characters followed by a non-space, using the Regex or | symbol, to match either type. Then, the first and last space of the three spaces will be the splits and the middle one will be preseverved, and this can be done in just one Regex.Replace and one Regex.Split.

```
'\s(?!\s)'
```

uses negative lookahead to match a space not followed by a  space, while

```
'(?<!\s)\s'
```

uses lookbehind to match a space not preceded by a space. Putting that together with or | you get

```
Regex.Replace("\s+","\s\s\s")
Regex.Split("(?<!\s)\s|\s(?!\s)")
```

Obviously the exact details might vary depending on your flavor of Regex, as some of them have differing interpretations, and might not support all the same commands.

Answer (score 1):

You may trim your input string when passing it to [`Regex.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx) and use a pattern that is almost identical to yours - `(\s)+`. Adding a capturing group to the pattern used with `Regex.Split` forces the engine to output the captured contents together with other non-matched chunks in the resulting array:

> If capturing parentheses are used in a [Regex.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx) expression, any captured text is included in the resulting string array. For example, if you split the string "plum-pear" on a hyphen placed within capturing parentheses, the returned array includes a string element that contains the hyphen.

The `(\s)+` pattern will find all 1+ whitespaces, but will only capture 1 single whitespace into the group memory buffer thus adding only this one whitespace into the final resulting array:

```
var temp="str1   str2   str3  ";
var pattern=@"(\s)+";
var tempArr=Regex.Split(temp.Trim(),pattern);
Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", string.Join("','", tempArr));
// => 'str1',' ','str2',' ','str3'
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/IiJe26)